# How do I open and edit a table in my geodatabase

Tags: arcgis-desktop, editing, file-geodatabase

I created a file geodatabase with some tables.  I created a new table and specified the field properties.
Now, how do I open the table to populate the fields?

Answer (score 4):

You open the table in ArcMap by adding the table or layer to the table of contents, right click on the layer and select *open attribute table* (if it's a table look for it in data view). Then you can use field calculator or edit the cells individually by clicking in them and entering data.

One more important thing, to edit cells in a table you must be editing, field calculator does not require you to be editing but gives an extra level of *undo* (the normal undo and you can always not save the edits).

Look at this page http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//005s00000038000000 for nice pictures and covering topics I have skipped over.

Comment: Yes, thank you. When I try to drag my table onto the TOC, I get an error message "could not add the specified data object to the map"

Comment: Don't drag 'n drop if you are having trouble with that. Open the table using the add data button. You can only drag a table into ArcMap when you are in the *data source view* and not in *selection*, *visibility* or *drawing order*, ArcMap should swap for you but may not - in that lies the problem.